# Woher kommt das umgangssprachliche S am Ende von »sagts«, »machts« usw. (2. Person Plural)?

Tags: dialect, colloquial, conjugation, bavarian

Ich bin heute in Facebook über dieses sprachliche Phänomen gestolpert, das ich zwar schon seit 50 Jahren kenne, worüber ich mir aber noch nie Gedanken gemacht habe:

Zumindest in Österreich wird bei Verben in der Du-Form in der 2. Person im Plural umgangssprachlich ein S ans Ende des Verbs angehängt:

> *Kommt**s*** her zu mir. (Umgangssprachlich)
>   *Kommt* her zu mir. (Standarddeutsch)
>
> Ihr *macht**s*** das falsch! (ugs.)
>   Ihr *macht* das falsch! (std.)
>
> Bitte *schreibt**s*** leserlich! (ugs.)
>   Bitte *schreibt* leserlich! (std.)
>
> *Wollt**s*** ihr einen Kuchen? (ugs.)
>   *Wollt* ihr einen Kuchen? (std.)

Wissts(!) ihr, woher dieses S am Ende des Verbs kommt? Mir fällt dazu nämlich überhaupt keine Erklärung ein. Mir fällt auch keine andere grammatische Situation ein, bei der einem Verb ein S angehängt wird.

Ist das eine österreichische oder süddeutsche Eigenheit, oder kommt dieses umgangssprachliche S auch weiter im Norden vor?

Könnts ihr mir helfen?

Comment: Fragmente, die bisher nicht zu einer Antwort reichen: Im Norden scheint es mir völlig unbekannt. (Ich falle mit Sätzen wie »ihr wissts doch« auf.) Es wäre zwar halbwegs logisch, würde es sich auf die ältere, bairische Form von *ihr, ees* zurückführen, aber selbst im Dialekt gibt es Sätze wie »Wissts ees ned, dass …«; die Dopplung erschiene mir unlogisch.

Comment: @Jan: Die Vermutung mit dem *ees* halte ich für wenig plausibel, weil das Wort *es* (oder *ees*) ein Rest eines Duals ist, also ursprünglich nur verwendet wurde, wenn ein Paar angesprochen wurde. Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(Grammatik)#Bairisch

Comment: Hm, aber vielleicht stammt es dann tatsächlich vom Dual ab … kurze Blicke auf die eine oder andere rekonstruierte Proto-Germanisch-Konjugation legen nahe, das ein *s*-Laut am Ende der 2. Person Dual gewesen ist, der sich dann entsprechend in die *Ihr*-Form  »hinübergerettet« hat …?

Comment: Müsste der erste Satz umgangssprachlich nicht "Kummts zuwa" heissen?

Comment: @Beta: »Kummts«: Ja, »zuwa«: Jein. Die Bairischen Dialekte sind ein Kontinuum von vielen verschiedenen Dialekten. In Wien und Umgebung ist »zuwa« zwar bekannt, aber wenig gebräuchlich. »Her« ist hier üblicher. Im Osten der Steiermark, wo ich ausgewachsen bin, und im Südburgenland sagt man »zuwi«. Aber mir ging es ja ohnehin nicht um die Vokabeln, sondern um die Grammatik, daher habe ich standarddeutsche Vokabel verwendet. Außerdem zeichnet sich die Umgangssprache auch dadurch aus, dass mehr Standardvokabel verwendet werden als in einem Dialekt.

Comment: @Jan Achtung: "Ihr wissts doch", "Ihr machts ja eh nicht",... ist ziemlich sicher was Anderes, als das was Hubert fragt (Nämlich ein verkürztes "es")

Comment: @tofro Achtung: »Ihr wissts doch« =/= »Ihr wissts as doch.« Gleichermaßen: »Ihr machts ja eh ned (des was ich sage)« =/= »Ihr machts as ja eh ned.« Ich wüsste nicht, ob ich die Formen hinterm Ungleichheitszeichen nicht besser als »machts’s« und »wissts’s« schreiben sollte (eher nicht, da ist noch ein Vokal irgendwo zwischen Schwa und e/a). Auf jeden Fall sind sie für mich klar verschieden und das *s* am Ende von Verbformen der zweiten Person Plural in keinem Fall ein verschliffenes *es*.

Comment: @Jan "Ihr wisst's doch eh schon, der Franz heiratet" ist mMn ein verkürztes "es" (in dem bairisch, das ich kenne, und auch in vielen anderen süddeutschen Dialekten) . "Ihr wisst's doch, dass der Franz heiratet", ist mMn worauf sich Hubert bezieht (und das **nur** in bairischen Dialekten, die anderen süddeutschen D. sagen "wisset")

Comment: @tofro Den ersten Satz würde ich eben als »Ihr wissts es doch eh schon, der Franz heiratet«, forumlieren. Eben weil mir sonst das *es* fehlt ;) Ich war mir nur nicht sicher, inwiefern sich diese Sprachgewohnheit, die ich aus dem Bairischen kenne, in andere Süddeutsche Dialekte verbreitet hat.

Comment: Erstens: Ich meinte nicht: »Ihr **wisst's** doch ohnehin schon, dass ...« Ich meinte aber sehr wohl: »Ihr **wissts es** doch ohnehin schon, dass ...« Im ersten Beispiel wurde das Pronomen in Form des »'s« an das Verb angefügt. Das ist, soweit ich weiß, im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum gängig. Im zweiten Beispiel steht das Pronomen explizit als eigenständiges Wort im Satz. Trotzdem wird an das Verb noch ein s angefügt. Meine Frage bezog sich auf genau dieses S.

Comment: Zweitens: Ich sprach ausdrücklich von der Umgangssprache, nicht von einem Dialekt. Dass Dialekte eine ganz andere Grammatik haben können als die Standardsprache, setze ich als bekannt voraus. Die Umgangssprache ist eine Mischform aus Dialekt und Standardsprache, und weist im Allgemeinen eine Grammatik auf, die der Grammatik der Standardsprache fast genau gleicht. Mir ist auch klar, dass regionale Dialekte die Umgangssprache beeinflussen, und dass die Grenze sehr unscharf und fließend ist. Und möglicherweise stammt das S auch aus so einem Einfluss. Aber es tritt eben nicht nur in Dialekten auf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laut M. Schuster und H. Schikola in "Sprachlehre der Wiener Mundart" (Wien 1984) ist dies ein Rest vom Dualis, und zwar hat sich hier das alte Dualispronomen "es" sich ans Ende des Verbes auf diesem Wege angehängt:

> Eine sehr eigenartige Erscheinung, die unsere Mundart mit dem gesamten Mittelbaierischen und einem Teil des Nordbaierischen teilt, ist die, daß sie das persönliche Fürwort sozusagen in die Biegung des Zeitwortes, der Eigenschaftswörter und anderer Wortgruppen eingebaut hat, ja die sogar zur "Biegung" von Vorwörtern verwendet.

Also derselbe Mechanismus als der, der Wortbildungen wie "Wenn*st* willst" geschaffen hat.

Warum hat dies nur die Wortformen der 2. Person beeinflusst? Man kan dies mit der Tatsache erklären, dass gerade bei der 2. Person kommt die Anrede vor, wo das Pronomen nach dem Verb steht. Z.B "Habt ihr das gemacht?" heisst dann "Habts (ihr) das gemacht?" Was von "Habt es das gemacht?" gekommen ist.  In dieser Kontext ist es leicht zu verstehen warum "ihr" weggelassen sein kann, das Pronomen ist ja schon da, in dem "-s".
Das Dualispronomen "es" ist in die Dialekten immernoch als "ös" lebendig "Habts ös?"

Comment: Eine Bemerkung, wieso das Phänomen vom Dualis auf den gesamten Plural übergesprungen ist, würde diese Antwort zusätzlich bereichern.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper diese Frage wird im oben genannten Buch nicht beantwortet, und es steht auch nichts darüber weder in Dudens "Wie sagt man in Österreich?" noch in  Hans Reis' "Die Deutschen Mundarten". Ich könnte mich aber vorstellen, dass wenn man im 12.-13. Jh nicht mehr zwischen Dualis und Plural unterschiedete, das eine oder das andere Pronomen (als Wort, nicht als Form) "gewonnen" hat. Im nördlichen Sprachraum hätte sich das Pluralwort eingewurzelt, im südlichen das Dualiswort.